# how to find records which has some specific values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have one log table in that i can check how many records inserted in which table.

i want to find that in which device has 0 records inserted from complete logs.

sample data

```
Id  DeviceID    Success RecordInserted  ErrorMessage    LogDate
1   0000ACFFFE4D48  1   395 NULL    2018-05-11 12:54:55.713
2   0000ACFFFE4E6A  1   492 NULL    2018-05-11 12:55:10.277
3   0000ACFFFE51D9  1   247 NULL    2018-05-11 12:55:17.790
4   0000ACFFFE5585  1   399 NULL    2018-05-11 12:55:28.267
5   0000ACFFFE5B03  1   493 NULL    2018-05-11 12:55:44.313
6   0000ACFFFE56E3  1   456 NULL    2018-05-11 12:56:00.743
7   0000ACFFFE1183  1   410 NULL    2018-05-11 12:56:09.817
8   0000ACFFFE2693  1   333 NULL    2018-05-11 12:56:24.613
9   0000ACFFFE4454  1   456 NULL    2018-05-11 12:56:36.867
10  0000ACFFFE7223  1   10056   NULL    2018-05-11 13:03:04.410
11  0000ACFFFE1CBB  1   10046   NULL    2018-05-11 13:06:03.860
12  0000ACFFFE2F81  1   0   NULL    2018-05-11 13:06:06.567
13  0000ACFFFE6F29  1   0   NULL    2018-05-11 13:06:08.307
14  0000ACFFFE0B8D  1   10078   NULL    2018-05-11 13:10:28.020
15  0000ACFFFE4DF2  1   409 NULL    2018-05-11 13:10:39.950
16  0000ACFFFE4D48  1   0   NULL    2018-05-11 13:16:32.027
17  0000ACFFFE4E6A  1   1   NULL    2018-05-11 13:16:38.640
18  0000ACFFFE51D9  1   1   NULL    2018-05-11 13:16:41.997
19  0000ACFFFE5585  1   1   NULL    2018-05-11 13:16:49.473
20  0000ACFFFE5B03  1   1   NULL    2018-05-11 13:16:56.797
21  0000ACFFFE56E3  1   1   NULL    2018-05-11 13:17:03.703
22  0000ACFFFE1183  1   0   NULL    2018-05-11 13:17:10.283
23  0000ACFFFE2693  1   1   NULL    2018-05-11 13:17:14.830
24  0000ACFFFE4454  1   0   NULL    2018-05-11 13:17:21.880
25  0000ACFFFE7223  1   64  NULL    2018-05-11 14:06:32.153
26  0000ACFFFE1CBB  1   64  NULL    2018-05-11 14:09:26.907
27  0000ACFFFE2F81  1   0   NULL    2018-05-11 14:09:28.743
28  0000ACFFFE6F29  1   0   NULL    2018-05-11 14:09:30.667
29  0000ACFFFE0B8D  1   64  NULL    2018-05-11 14:11:42.227
30  0000ACFFFE4DF2  1   3   NULL    2018-05-11 14:11:48.857
```

Expected output

```
0000ACFFFE6F290B
0000ACFFFE2F818D
```

This 2 deviceid have 0 recordinserted

sql query

```
  select deviceid from logs where recordinserted !=0 and deviceid in (select deviceid from logs where recordinserted= '0')
```

**error**

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for devices with zero entries?  Or devices whose entries total 0 RecordsInserted?  I do not see your expected output Ids in the list and this Id '0000ACFFFE2F81' has two entries both with 0 Records Inserted.

For DeviceIds that are not listed, DeviceId needs to be a foreign key to another table, and you can find those that are not in the logs table with this query:

```
SELECT Id FROM DeviceTable
EXCEPT 
SELECT DeviceId FROM Logs
```

To get those that have a sum total of 0 records in the Logs Table use this query:

```
SELECT DeviceId
      ,SUM(RecordsInserted)
FROM Logs
GROUP BY DeviceId
Having SUM(RecordsInserted) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select deviceid from logs where recordinserted = 0
```

You can use the where clause like this when recordinserted column is integer type.

Answer (score 0):

```
select deviceid 
from logs
group by deviceid
having max(recordinserted) = 0 -- no row greater zero exists
```